# Android Studio says"Mainactivity is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml"?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, declare

This is my manifest file when i run the app it says "Main Activity is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml"

I tried Rebuilding,invalidate caches/restart,adding

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"  to my manifest
```

also many other things from other answers on stockoverflow but didnt solved my problem. please help me.
i made a apk yesterday till then it worked fine but today when i opened it it showed this error.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.keval.raagbhandaar">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".pprath">
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".mpurn" />
            <activity android:name=".mprath" />
            <activity android:name=".Prambhik" />
            <activity android:name=".Exams" />



            <activity android:name=".Kalyan"/>
            <activity android:name=".Thats" />
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.keval.raagbhandaar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivityexam();


            }

            public void openActivityexam() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Exams.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        });
    }}
```

logcat

2019-03-14 17:02:33.492 5363-5363/com.keval.raagbhandaar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.keval.raagbhandaar, PID: 5363
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(558306000bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:19450)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19386)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19183)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: What is package name of your main activity?

Comment: Is the file itself named exactly "MainActivity.java"? Because you've typed out "MainActivity" three different ways in your short post.

Comment: I recreated the app and copied & pasted your manifest and it runs correctly. You must be leaving out a detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two scenarios.

1) you have your `MainActivity.java` class but you haven't created `activity_main.xml` thats why you didn't declared you Activity in your android manifest.

2) You have your both java class and xml class but you didn't declared your activity in android manifest.

**NOTE**: **This issue only occur when you forgot to declare your activity in android manifest.**

Comment: how to declare that

Comment: make sure you have your MainActivity.java class in your project.

Comment: its here  app->java->com.keval.raagbhandaar->Here

Comment: i have the MainActivity.java file   app->java->com.keval.raagbhandaar->Here

Comment: try this:  File -> sync project with gradle files..and let me know if it works!

Comment: now the error is not coming but the app in emulator is not working

Comment: the app doesnt work when i click a button it shows app stopped

Comment: aah! problem is you must have added high resolution image in your android project..remove it and use low resolution image.

Answer (score 1):

Following possibilities for this error.

1. You forgot to extend your Activity

   ```
   class MainActvity extends AppCompatActivity
   ```
2. You are using the wrong package name to register your activity

   ```
        <activity
           android:name="com.keval.raagbhandaar.MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   ```

As per your package name :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.keval.raagbhandaar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.keval.raagbhandaar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please do the corrections and give the code i dont understand

Comment: What is the package name of your activity? you can also try with alt+space and the android studio will give a suggestion. Then add activity.

Comment: my mainactivity.xml is here   res->layout->HERE

Comment: No, where is your java file? MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt

Comment: app->java->com.keval.raagbhandaar->Here

Comment: still says the same

Comment: can you post your java file also here?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have generated project as per your package name. It is working properly.

Comment: It might be some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.MainActivity` is your classpath ?

You need to set the entire path like "`.myfolder.MainActivity`" ?

Comment: didnt understood .what you want to tell explain please

Comment: E.g : if your Main Activity class is in this structure folder : ui -> main -> MainActivity. The declaration should be .ui.main.MainActivity

Comment: class is the xml file or the java file?

Comment: The java file. MainActivity.java

Comment: my MainActivity.java file is here  app->java->com.keval.raagbhandaar->Here

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your error of log 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(558306000bytes) bitmap. at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229) at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97) at

It is saying that image you are using is large size please try to reduce image size and run again. May be it will work